# How to install latest Grafana on FreeBSD?

Tags: software-installation, freebsd

The latest version of Grafana in ports and `pkg install` is 1.9.1, which doesn't support prometheus. Is there a way to install latest version of Grafana on FreeBSD (4.5.2)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The FreeBSD ports tree contains, [as far as I can see](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/ports.cgi?query=grafana&stype=all&sektion=www), `grafana` (1.9.1), `grafana2` (2.6.0), `grafana3` (3.1.1) and `grafana4` (4.5.1).

To install `grafana` version 4.5.1, use the `grafana4` port.

If you *really* want version 4.5.2, I'd suggest first contacting the ports maintainer (see above link) to see if they're working on it before trying to compile it yourself.

Comment: my bad! 4.5.1 should be fine for me. I just need prometheus support at the minimum. thanks!

Comment: [There seems to be files related to that in the port](https://svnweb.freebsd.org/ports/head/www/grafana4/pkg-plist?revision=450025&view=markup#l1071).

Comment: yes, thanks. grafana started supporting prometheus from 2.5.